# How to Enforce Set-Cookie Header for Sessions When Backend is on AWS and Frontend is on localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, session-cookies

I'm working on a web development project where my backend is hosted on AWS, and my frontend is running locally on http://127.0.0.1:5173. I'm having difficulty enforcing the Set-Cookie header for sessions.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the Set-Cookie header appears to be blocked or not properly configured when I try to run my application.
I get the following error message, "this attempt to set a cookie via a set cookie header was blocked because it had the sameSite=lax attribute but came from a cross site response which was not the response to a top level navigation".
Here's how my Express session middleware is set up:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'lax',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
  })
);
```

My cors settings:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
}));
```

I suspect the issue might be related to CORS or the way I've configured my session cookies, given that the frontend and backend are on different origins.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? What are the correct CORS or cookie settings to enforce the Set-Cookie header in this setup?

Ive also attached my full app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const app = express();
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const order = require("./routes/order");
const session = require("express-session");
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);
const env = require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://app.local.example.com:5173",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const options = {
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.NAME,
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

sessionStore
  .onReady()
  .then(() => {
    // MySQL session store ready for use.
    console.log("MySQLStore ready");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Something went wrong.
    console.error(error);
  });

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,

    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "lax",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      domain: ".local.example.com",
    },
  })
);

require("./config/passportConfig");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/api/account", auth);
app.use("/api/order", order);

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3003...");
});
```

Modified CORS settings:
Updated the CORS settings on the backend to match the frontend's local address (http://127.0.0.1:5173), including setting credentials: true.

Adjusted Cookie Settings:
Changed various attributes in the cookie object in the session middleware, including httpOnly, secure, and sameSite, to see if any of these were causing the issue.

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know: browsers won't let a cross-site response set a cookie marked `SameSite=Lax`. A necessary condition for that to work is to mark the cookie in question `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.